# repl.bat : Using Regular Expressions in the Replace Parameter

Tags: batch-file, replace

I have a question with regards to using the 'repl' batch command, specifically it's replace parameter.

After taking the time to read the documentation... :-)... and some testing, it seems that regular expressions can't be used in the replace parameter.

"type file.txt | repl "Jacob is alive. He lives.\n" "Betty lives.\nGo Betty." M >file.txt.new"

This will do a literal replace using the characters '.' & '\n' rather than inserting a new line.  Is it true regular expressions cannot be used in the [replace] parameter of repl.bat?  If not, do you know of a way to achieve this behavior?  Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: Since repl.bat does not come standard with Windows, you should provide a link to it so that people who aren't familiar with it can help.

Comment: My apologies.  Here is the original post of repl.bat [link](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3855} and the earliest StackOverflow post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034/how-can-you-find-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-the-windows-command-line-envir/16735079#16735079) from @dbenham.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extracted from the `repl.bat /?` information

```
    M - Multi-line mode. The entire contents of stdin is read and
        processed in one pass instead of line by line, thus enabling
        search for \n. This also enables preservation of the original
        line terminators. If the M option is not present, then every
        printed line is termiated with carriage return and line feed.
        The M option is incompatible with the A option unless the S
        option is also present.

    X - Enables extended substitution pattern syntax with support
        for the following escape sequences within the Replace string:

        \\     -  Backslash
        \b     -  Backspace
        \f     -  Formfeed
        \n     -  Newline
        \q     -  Quote
        \r     -  Carriage Return
        \t     -  Horizontal Tab
        \v     -  Vertical Tab
        \xnn   -  Extended ASCII byte code expressed as 2 hex digits
        \unnnn -  Unicode character expressed as 4 hex digits
```

So, your `repl` command *options* should be `MX` instead of only `M`

Comment: Ah, I was on the right track.  I had tried that, but had separated the M and X in the options & that was causing it grief.  This appears to work great!  Thanks!